# How to add multiple labels and points in OpenLayers 3 using WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

I have India country WMS layer, and I want to add label for each state and point or small circle for each state. I created a layer from GeoServer using a PostgreSQL database. Using the database how can I show the labels and points for each state with OpenLayers 3?

Comment: You will have to create an SLD file http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/

Comment: Thanks ,but how to use wms url path in the sld code,i wan't to display  lable and points  using database and display on wms layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So several things, 
First, you can assign for a database table (a layer) a default style see here [geoserverdocs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/webadmin/index.html)

You can have red points with a green label if you like.

Second with WMS you can request a different style to the default one. This is done with the the key STYLE:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
request=GetMap
&service=WMS
&version=1.1.1
&layers=topp%3Astates
&styles=population
&srs=EPSG%3A4326
&bbox=-145.15104058007,21.731919794922,-57.154894212888,58.961058642578&
&width=780
&height=330
&format=image%2Fpng
```

With OpenLayers you would do :

```
 var layer= new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: layerTitle,
            layerType: 'WMS',
            legend: 'query',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'url',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                params: {
                    'VERSION': "1.1.1",
                    'LAYERS': 'layername'
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    'transparent': true,
                    'STYLES' : sld,
                    'format': 'application/openlayers',

                },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks sir for giving solution.Sir I have one question,If I wan't to display map,layer,point and label or anything from PostgreSQL database using leaflet or open-layer,Then is there necessary to query in PHP and use java script or directly I use database from Geo-server .I new for this so I confused a lot.So If I use PHP then how to connect front end languages.Thanks

Comment: No need for Sir... I dont really get your question. But you just need to request Geoserver though WMS /WFS HTTP Requests. As shown above you can do this with ol3.